# Configuring JSDom in an async mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, jsdom

I'm trying to load my dependencies into a JSDom environment then execute a basic test.

When I run this file with mocha, it tells me that the maximum timeout of 2000 milliseconds has been exceeded.

```
// Node Dependencies
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// NPM Dependencies
import { expect } from 'expect';
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';

// JSDom Configuration
const html    = '<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>';
const dep1    = readFileSync("./dep1.js", "utf-8");
const dep2    = readFileSync("./dep2.js", "utf-8");
const scripts = [ dep1, dep2 ];

describe('App Actions', function(){
  it('sample test', function(done){

    // Use JSDom to mock a browser environment,
    // loading the necessary scripts, then executing the callback.
    jsdom(html, scripts, callback);

    function callback(err, window){
      expect(false).toEqual(true);
      done();
    }

  });
});
```

Any ideas?

I think it has something do with jsdom, since if I change the callback to look like this:

```
function callback(err, window){
  console.log(window);
  expect(false).toEqual(true);
  done();
}
```

It never runs the `console.log`.

Comment: Maybe passing `callback` to jsdom before you define it?

Comment: It's being hoisted above the invocation of `jsdom(html, scripts, callback)`. Same issue if I move the callback above.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `jsdom.jsdom` but using the syntax for `jsdom.env` (which does expect a callback as a third parameter). Change this line:

```
import { jsdom } from 'jsdom';
```

To:

```
import { env } from 'jsdom';
```